# Delphi + Linux + Threads = memory

Tags: linux, multithreading, delphi

Have a memory problem. Small app (server on few ports, TMS+Indy, Delphi 10.3) is using about 2 Gb of memory (to compare - only 6 Mb under Windows).

So, small test, almost empty console app:

```
var x: TThread;
begin
    x := TThread.Create(true);
```

after Create (looking internally - after **pthread_create**) "pmap" in Ubuntu says that few memory blocks was added as: 4 kb + 132 kb + 8192 kb + 65404 kb

4 + 132 kb - not too large, ok

8 mb - looks as default stack size for a thread, ok

but what is 64 Mb????

Comment: "*8 mb - looks as default stack size for a thread*" - the default thread stack size on Linux is 2 MB, unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: "2 MB" - Yes, thank you.
"unless you specify otherwise" - No manual changes, question is about default Delphi behaviour - and I can't find why...

Comment: pmap tells you what each block is, for example `00007fff04aca000    132K rw---   [ stack ]`- so what was it?

Comment: I don't have any experience developing multithreaded applications for Linux but if my memory serves me correctly in Delphi 10.3 Linux application rely on ARC (Automatic Reference Counting). So I recommend checking of how your multithreading is implemented to make sure that your thread objects are getting destroyed when expected and not remain alive due the fact that their ReferenceCount never reaches zero.

Comment: Found a point. Thread initialization in Delphi calls __malloc and requests 2Kb - but really 64Mb is allocated... Seems problem is memory manager... /// 

Brian, 132K rwx-- [anon], 8Mb rwx-- [anon], 64Mb ----- [anon]

Comment: Looks like it grabs an allocation of 64 MB for the heap. The --- means it is not actually in use however. Should be two (or more) allocations listed that together add up to 64MB (65,536KB) with the other allocation(s) having flags showing they are in use.

Answer (score 3):

The `pmap` entry is not the consumed memory, it is the reserved/mapped memory.

RAM is first reserved/mapped, but actually consumed per page (typically 4KB), the first time a page is accessed by the program.

IIRC under Linux, the Delphi memory manager is just a wrapper around the libc `malloc free` API calls. It is typical for this MM to reserve some per-thread memory pages for the thread-specific memory arena. I guess 64MB is a plausible value.

So don't be afraid about those numbers. They don't imply that your RAM chips are consumed eagerly. You can have a process reserving GB of memory, but actually only using a few 100MB of hardware RAM - the `writeable/private` value in `pmap`. And note that a Delphi app will consume typically lower than any GC program. :)

*Update/Proposal after comments:*
If you need to reduce memory, don't use threads, but non-blocking inet libraries, or a thread pool and a reverse proxy (e.g. nginx) to maintain the inet connections. You can have your server handle HTTP/1.0 in a thread pool, and your nginx proxy maintain HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 long standing connections. If you use Posix sockets between nginx and the service on the loopback, it is very efficient. We use this configuration with our mORMot services on high production Linux systems, with great stability.

*Update/More Info:*
This 64MB mapping seems indeed the per-thread-arena reserved mapped memory from malloc. Check https://codearcana.com/posts/2016/07/11/arena-leak-in-glibc.html and MALLOC_ARENA_MAX as detailed in https://siddhesh.in/posts/malloc-per-thread-arenas-in-glibc.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My app looks small, but I'm using libraries that creates number of threads (on each inet connection), and each takes 64Mb - so memory using is 1-2 Gb (other app more that 2Gb - we have few services on the same engine). My admin says that server is *really* overloaded. So, question is - can I control memory allocation? Who decides what amount to reserve?

Comment: @gribulon This is a libc responsability. If you admin says that server is overloaded, then it means that he/she can't make a difference between memory reserved/mapped and memory actually allocated. Only the later matters on 64-bit systems. In `pmap`, "`mapped`" memory is not the meaningful entry - " `writeable/private`" is the value to take into consideration about system loading.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm checked few docs and seems now I know how it works ))